# Error creating bean with the name localContainerEntityManagerFactorryBean defined in the class path resource hibernateconfig.class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate-session

I'm getting the Error creating **bean** with the name **localContainerEntityManagerFactorryBean** defined in the class path resource **hibernateconfig.class**. nested exception is **javax.persistence.persistenceException**:unable to build hibernate session factory: A foreign key referring organizer from events has the wrong no of column, should be 2.

```
My pom file is 
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>com.EventToday</groupId>
        <artifactId>EventToday</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
    
        <name>EventToday</name>
        <description>projects for events</description>
    
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
    
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
            <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
            <mysql.version>5.1.31</mysql.version>
            <joda-time.version>2.3</joda-time.version>
            <testng.version>6.9.4</testng.version>
            <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
            <h2.version>1.4.187</h2.version>
            <dbunit.version>2.2</dbunit.version>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency> 
            <!-- Hibernate -->
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>               
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
            <!-- jsr303 validation -->
            <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
            
            <!-- MySQL -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
                <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>18.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Joda-Time -->      
            <dependency>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            
            <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->         
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
                <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
            </dependency>
            
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                <scope>compile</scope>
                <optional>true</optional>
             </dependency>
             <dependency>
                  <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                  <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            
        </dependencies>
        
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                            <warName>EventToday</warName>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                        <compilerArgs>
                                 <arg>-Aopenjpa.metamodel=true</arg>
                        </compilerArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

and hibernate configuration

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaRepositories("com.EventToday.event.repository")
    @ComponentScan({ "com.EventToday.event" })
    @PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
    public class hibernateconfig {
    
            @Autowired
            private Environment environment;
    
            @Bean
            public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
                HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
                vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
                //vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(generateDDL);
                vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
                
                LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean beanFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
                beanFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    
                beanFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.EventToday.event.model");
    
                beanFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    
                //beanFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
                beanFactory.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
                
                return beanFactory;
             }
            
    
            
            @Bean
            public DataSource dataSource() {
                DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
                dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.driverClassName"));
                dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
                dataSource.setSchema(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.schema"));
                dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
                dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
                return dataSource;
            }
            
            private Properties hibernateProperties() {
                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
                properties.put("spring.jpa.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));
                properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql"));
                return properties;        
            }
            
            @Bean
            public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(){
                return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject();
            }
    
    
            @Bean
            public EntityManager entityManager(){
                return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
            }
    
            @Bean
            PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
                JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
                manager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
                return manager;
            }
    
            @Bean
            public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator(){
                return  new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
            }       
    }
```

## organizer

```
@Entity
@Table(name="organizer")
public class Organizer extends BaseEntity{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int roid;
    
    @Column(name="orgNname", nullable=false)
    private String organizerName;
    
    @Column(name = "org_contact", nullable = false)
    private String orgTelephone;
    
    @Column(name = "org_altcontact", nullable = false)
    private String orgContact;
    
    @Column(name = "org_mail_address", nullable = false)
    private String mailAddress;
    
    @Column(name = "org_address", nullable = false)
    private String orgAddress;
    
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "organizer")
      private Set<events> evts;
      
      


    public Set<events> getEvts() {
        return evts;
    }

    public void setEvts(Set<events> evts) {
        this.evts = evts;
    }

    public Organizer() {
    
    }

    //getters and setters
```

}

```
#events
@Entity
@Table(name="event")
public class events extends BaseEntity{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "roid")
    private Organizer organizer;

    public events() {
        
    }
    
    @Column(name = "event_name", nullable = false)
    private String eventname;
    
    @Column(name = "event_date", nullable = false)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
    private LocalDate date;
    
    
    @NotNull
    @Digits(integer=8, fraction=2)
    @Column(name = "ticket_price", nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal price;
    
    @Column(name="event_location", nullable=false)
    private String location;
    
    @Column(name="happening_city", nullable=false)
    private String Address;
    
    @Column(name="contact_no", nullable=false)
    private String contact_no;
    
    @Column(name="alt_contact_no", nullable=false)
    private String alternate_contact;
    
    @Column(name="mail_address")
    private String mail_address;
    
    //getters and setters
```

}

Comment: can you past your event class

Comment: @kuhajeyan event class is on the second part/div, sorry question doesn't look organized.

Comment: Your Organizer entity, which you didn't post despite being mentioned in the error message, seems to have a composite primary key. But you're using a single join column to refer to it in the events entity (which should be named Event, BTW). Post the relevant code, and please respect the Java naming conventions. Classes start with an uppercase letter, and fields never contain an underscore, and are camelCased.

Comment: @JBNizet I've corrected my self about respecting java naming conventions, in my project. I just edited my question. I'm not sure about the declaration of composite key, i just wanted to have primary key only.

Comment: it didn't solve my problem